# Take a 2D list of any even dimensions and return a list holding the count of thing for each 2 X 2 grid (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I am trying to make a function that will take a list such as:

```
l = [["A", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     ["A", "A", 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
     ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
     ["A", 3, "A", 4, "A", "A"],
     [1, 3, 5, "A", 5, "A"]
     ]
```

and a key, for example "A". And will give a list containing an int based on how many times KEY appears in the 2D list in every 2x2 cell. So for example a function

```
def count_in_grids(l, key):
```

will return

```
[3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

So far I have really bad code that I wrote. I am generally having trouble manipulating 2D lists. Since this is actually an assignment I am not allowed to use any library. If anyone can help me comprehend and write this, I will deeply appreciate it.

My crappy code that I wrote so far:

```
def countInGrids(l, thing):
new_list = []  # created a final list that will be returned
count = 0
for line in range(0, len(l), 2):  # Access lines
    for el in range(0, line, 2):  # Access elements
        #count + count() of all elements in line[el] to line[el+1], 
        move 2 lines down and repeat.
        count += line[line[el]:line[el]+1].count(thing) 
        count += line+1[line[el]:line[el]+1].count(thing)

        new_list.append(count)
print(new_list)
return new_list
```

OUTPUT:
line 63, in countInGrids
    count += line[line[el]:line[el]+1].count(thing)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

P.S: If anyone is wondering, this is my 1st semester CS Lab

Comment: `for line in range(0, len(l), 2):` results in `line` being an integer number. But within your loop you try to index it like an array or a list. That's the error message here.

Comment: Because I've been re-editing this one method for the whole day today, I've missed such simple error. I tried running this method using for x in list before, but still didn't work because I didn't really understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a bit clunky, but list comprehensions are always an option.

```
def countInGrid(grid, key):
    return [sum([v[i:i+2].count(key) for v in grid[j:j+2]])
            for j in range(0, len(grid), 2) for i in range(0, len(grid[0]), 2)]
```

Going through this, what it's using to come up with the 2x2 grids is `[v[i:i+2] for v in grid[j:j+2]`. This isn't a super efficient operation if you're doing it to the entire list of lists a bunch of times, but it's fast to write.

To count the key, it first counts in each row with `.count(key)`, and then it adds it up for each of the 2 rows in your 2x2 grid using `sum()`.

The last line is how you're selecting which 2x2 grid you want to look at. It specifies where you'll start and where you'll end. The order of `i` and `j` is important if you don't want to iterate through columns and then through rows.

The list comprehension basically has all of the following small components wrapped up into a tighter syntax.

```
def count_row(v, key):
    return v.count(key)

def count_grid(grid, key):
    return sum(count_row(v, key) for v in grid)

def get_nxn(grid, i, j, n=2):
    return [v[i:i+n] for v in grid[j:j+n]]

def iter_block_row(grid, j):
    for i in range(0, len(grid[0]), 2):
        yield get_nxn(grid, i, j)

def iter_grid(grid):
    for j in range(0, len(grid), 2):
        # In Python 3.3+, use
        # yield from iter_block_row(grid, j)
        for g in iter_block_row(grid, j):
            yield g

def count_in_grid(grid, key):
    return [count_grid(g, key) for g in iter_grid(grid)]
```

Thinking about big problems as being composed of small parts helps to make them manageable with any amount of experience. It's also helpful to see that you don't need any of the extra syntactic sugar and language tricks to accomplish the same goal in a clean way.

**Note** the slices in `get_nxn()` are super inefficient. This is one way to decompose the problem (and I think the easiest way to think about conceptually), but it is NOT the most efficient.

**Update** I was wrong about the `get_nxn()` inefficiency. It looks like list slices in Python don't copy data, even as far back as Python 2.7+. The `get_nxn()` operation runs in constant time with respect to the size of `grid`, and it's a fast constant time at that.

Comment: Oh wow! You did it in less than a minute. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it, especially because it's due today. Am I really that bad at CS though.... Took me an hour to NOT find a solution ;(

Comment: Programming takes practice. The key is to break things up into small, easily understandable parts. In just a second I'll edit the answer with a better style that'd be easier to understand.

Comment: Ah! I understand what you did here.  From your explanation I can tell I didn't use slices properly and I didn't correctly index my lists. I better read up tonight on list and its built-in functions. Thank you again for this explanation and breaking down this to me, I deeply appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It's tempting to try for a solution with slicing and comprehensions right off the bat, but I think the risk of confusion is sufficiently high that it's OK to start with a naive solution.

The first step is to locate all corners of the sub-squares:

```
1 . 2 . 3 .
. . . . . .
4 . 5 . 6 .
. . . . . .
7 . 8 . 9 .
. . . . . .
```

This is a nested loop counting by 2 where a corner cell is located at `(row, col)`.

Given a sub-square, traversing its cells is another pair of nested loops with a step of 1:

```
1 2 x . x .
3 4 . . . .
x . x . x .
. . . . . .
x . x . x .
. . . . . .
```

Here, each element is located at `(row + i, col + j)` where `i` and `j` are inner loop steps.

After that, it's a matter of writing a conditional test and appending a counter for each sub-square to the result list.

Lastly, add the step size as a default parameter to increase reusability.

Putting it together:

```
def count_in_grids(l, key, size=2):
    result = []

    for row in range(0, len(l), size):
        for col in range(0, len(l[row]), size):
            result.append(0)

            for i in range(size):
                for j in range(size):
                    if key == l[row+i][col+j]:
                        result[-1] += 1

    return result

print(count_in_grids(l, "A"))
```

Comment: Not to be too pedantic since it expresses a longer runtime for bigger objects quite well, but the overhead for slicing would only be an extra linear factor. You'd still have a low-order polynomial runtime. Also, I just looked into it a little deeper, and list slices are views into the original list; aside from a constant number of pointer lookups however they implemented that, there isn't any overhead in taking lots of big, overlapping slices.

Comment: In the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) under "3.1.4. Lists" it says that slices return a new list containing the selected elements (making this tantamount to a shallow copy). Since lists are pass-by-reference in Python, this list of lists will be stored as a list of references (crudely bechmarkable for confirmation -- time the creation of a large list `L` compared to the list `[L]`).

Comment: That said, I do like your pedagogical approach. There's something to be said for starting out with straight loops and working from there.

Comment: I [benchmarked](https://repl.it/repls/MuddySickWorkspaces), and you're right, your approach is more efficient which is educational and surprising to me. I removed that component of my answer, which I'll leave up for a bit longer to see if it contributes, but yeah, it seems like Python can optimize your code better than regular for loops.

Comment: My approach does have some object creation overhead, and I'm personally also surprised that it's faster. I didn't think it was leaps and bounds worse per se, but faster is unexpected. I think you might be able to get loops faster if you pre-initalized `res` instead of doing O(n^2) appends and if we found some way to get around the two accessors and two additions which have to be computed sequentially and can't be pipelined in `l[row+i][col+j]`.

Comment: Yeah, so the direct loop-based approach is faster when you replace the inner ranges with slices to get your 2x2 blocks. Also, both versions are sped up substantially by avoiding `.count()` and just manually adding the two things. That probably isn't true for large block sizes. The `sum()` builtin has a similar issue. Refactoring both approaches to avoid small inner ranges, not use `sum()`, and not use `count()`, both have comparable runtimes (and a 30-50% speed boost).